# How to stream s3 file as input for GPG encryption and meanwhile stream the encrypted data back to s3 using Python?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, gnupg

I have a large file in aws s3. I want to use Python to take s3 file stream as input for GPG encryption, in the meantime, stream the encrypted data back to s3 until the encryption is done. so that the encrypted data will not blow memory.

The process should be:  (s3 stream) -> (GPG Encrption Stream) -> (s3 stream).

I have tried below code, but gnupg library doesn't support streambody as input. Is there another way to do this?

```
import boto3
import gnupg
gpg = gnupg.GPG()
imported_keys = gpg.import_keys(key_data)
s3_object = s3.get_object(Bucket=Bucket, Key=Key)['Body']
encrypted_data = gpg.encrypt(s3_object, armor=False, always_trust=True, recipients = imported_keys.fingerprints)
```

I also have tried below code, but there is no output file in s3.

```
from smart_open import open
gpg.encrypt_file(open('s3://Bucket/key/test.txt','rb'), armor=False, always_trust=True, recipients = imported_keys.fingerprints, output='s3://Bucket/key/test.gpg')
```

Comment: Did you get solution? Even I have the same requirement

Answer (score 3):

use on_data feature of gpg

```
import gnupg
import s3fs

gpg = gnupg.GPG()
imported_keys = gpg.import_keys(key_data)
file_input = 's3://Bucket/key/test.txt'
file_output = 's3://Bucket/key/test.txt.gpg'
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)
class Capturer(object):
    def __init__(self, file_output, fs):
        self.fout = fs.open(file_output, 'wb')

    def __call__(self, data):
        if data:
            self.fout.write(data)
        else:
            self.fout.close()
        return False


capturer = Capturer(file_output, fs)
gpg.on_data = capturer

with fs.open(file_input, 'rb') as fin:
    status = gpg.encrypt_file(fin,armor=False, always_trust=True, recipients = imported_keys.fingerprints)
```